# Using Android Studio for none compatible device

Tags: android, compatibility

What happens if someone uses android Studio to develop Apps which are running on none compatible Android device. Does Google sue you?

Answer (score -1):

No google will not sue you :) 
Apps which are running on none compatible Android devices are authorized.

Comment: The compat policy tells different. You are not allowed to use android Studio for none compat devices